# Newid() SQLCE to MySQL Row Conversion Replacement

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, sql-server

i have a SQL-Server CE Edition database i have exported and have all tables ported back into MySQL database, i have a few questions on how i should tackle the way they are Using there ID Row
her is there SQLServer CE Export,

```
CREATE TABLE [ReturnStation] (
  [ID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid())

, [DivertForNoReads] nvarchar(255) NULL
, [DivertForDuplicate] nvarchar(255) NULL
, [DivertForIDRange] nvarchar(255) NULL
, [DivertForTr] nvarchar(255) NULL
```

in MySQL  i just have

```
  `ID` tinyint NOT NULL,
```

i have never ran into this Schema before, so i am wondering how do i get the same functionality in the MySQL row ,

```
Thank you for all your help
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use a `binary(16)` and assign a `uuid()` to it.  But if you can use an integer, I would recommend that:

```
CREATE TABLE [ReturnStation] (
  [ID] int auto_increment primary key,
```

That said, you'll need to change all foreign key references to be an integer.  You would have to change them anyway.